# kendo reupload custom button click event once file is upload success

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have implemented kendo plugin for uploading file & its working fine.

**i am trying to re-upload the same file(currently uploaded file), during click event.**

I checked in the kendo form, they suggest to use

```
        $(".k-file .k-icon").removeClass("k-delete").addClass("k-retry").click();
```

Unfortunately this will work only when file upload is fail...

How can i re-uploaded the uploaded file ?

Answer (score -1):

i asume that you alrady see link http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/upload if not try this, ping if not success, maybe to just additional info do you whant remove file button all just replace uploaded one?

Comment: This does not answer the question and only directs the user to the main Kendo UI documentation for the upload widget.